# Generate random passwords in shell with one special character

Tags: bash, shell, unix, random, passwords

I have the following code:

```
</dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9@#$%&_+=' | head -c 16
```

which is randomly generating passwords perfectly.

I want two changes:

1. It should only contain one special character listed above
2. It should choose a random length

I tried with `length = $(($RANDOM%8+9))`

then putting length as

```
</dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9@#$%&_+=' | head -c$length
```

but got no positive result.

Comment: `length = ...` with the spaces isn't a valid shell assignment. I'm assuming that wasn't the problem you were having with the length piece. For the first part you'll need to validate and discard non-matching passwords I think. Alternatively use a "random" password generator like `pwqgen` (note: not `pwgen`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash
chars='@#$%&_+='
{ </dev/urandom LC_ALL=C grep -ao '[A-Za-z0-9]' \
        | head -n$((RANDOM % 8 + 9))
    echo ${chars:$((RANDOM % ${#chars})):1}   # Random special char.
} \
    | shuf \
    | tr -d '\n'
```

- `LC_ALL=C` prevents characters like ř from appearing.
- `grep -o` outputs just the matching substring, i.e. a single character.
- `shuf` shuffles the lines. I originally used `sort -R`, but it kept the same characters together (`ff1@22MvbcAA`).

Comment: @ArpitParasana: Check the improved version.

Comment: just for clarity: `${chars:$((RANDOM % 8)):1}` => `${chars:$((RANDOM % ${#chars})):1}`. Or is it unrelated? Why 8?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca: Yes, 8 is the length of the string.

Comment: @choroba: how long have you been doing this? :D

Comment: @EugeniuRosca: You mean this script? Couple of minutes. I've written a similar one for my purposes before.

Comment: @choroba: no. I mean scripting, in general. It seems too elegant compared to my try :p

Comment: @EugeniuRosca: Oh, scripting. 15 years, maybe more :-)

Comment: @choroba: terrifying!

Comment: per above code, how to assign the random password to a variable? Thanks

Comment: random_pass(){
chars='@#$%&_+='
rp=$({ </dev/urandom LC_ALL=C grep -ao '[A-Za-z0-9]' \
        | head -n$((RANDOM % 8 + 9))
    echo ${chars:$((RANDOM % ${#chars})):1}   # Random special char.
} \
    | shuf \
    | tr -d '\n')
echo ${rp}   
}

Answer (score 0):

```bash
## Objective: Generating Random Password:
function random_password () {
    [[ ${#1} -gt 0 ]] && { local length=${1}; } || { local length=16; }
    export DEFAULT_PASSWORDLENGTH=${length};
    export LC_CTYPE=C;
    local random="$(
        tr -cd "[:graph:]" < /dev/urandom \
        | head -c ${length} \
        | sed -e 's|\`|~|g' \
              -e 's|\$(|\\$(|g';
      )";
    echo -e "${random}";
    return 0;
  }; alias random-password='random_password';

$ random-password 32 ;
)W@j*deZ2#eMuhU4TODO&eu&r)&.#~3F

# Warning: Do not consider these other options

# date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 | xargs -0;
# Output: MGFjNDlhMTE2ZWJjOTI4OGI4ZTFiZmEz

# dd if=/dev/urandom count=200 bs=1 2>/dev/null \
# | tr -cd "[:graph:]" \
# | cut -c-${length} \
# | xargs -0;
# Output: AuS*D=!wkHR.4DZ_la
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.