# Creating a password in Bash

Tags: bash, passwords

I currently have a password that is being generated, that is a hash of the date. I'd like to increase this generated password's security, by adding in some uppercase, lower case, numeric, and special characters, all to a minimum length of 10 characters.

What I currently have is below. As you can see, it assigns the output to my PASSWORD variable.

```
PASSWORD=$(date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 15)
```

I'm unsure if I can do this inline, or, if I need to create a function within my bash script to suit? Is that even possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to install and use pwgen.

Comment: What you currently have is very weak because of lack of entropy.  The entropy is equivalent to the data.  This can easily be brute forced.  The answer from Cyrus below uses a much better source of input entropy: /dev/urandom.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947873/random-password-generate-in-shell-script-with-one-special-character

Comment: Strength of password would increase if you increase its length, even if you don't increase its underlying alphabet. For instance, a password that is 50 characters long, which is composed of **all** the same characters, is a strong password.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `tr` and `head`:

```
password=$(tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!?%=' < /dev/urandom | head -c 10)

echo "$password"
```

Output (example):

```
k?lmyif6aE
```

---

`tr` reads bytes via stdin from Linux‘ special random device [/dev/urandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) and removes all bytes/characters but `A` to `Z`, `a` to `z`, `0` to `9` and `!?%=`. `tr` sends its output via stdout to `head`‘s stdin. `head` cuts output after 10 bytes.

Comment: I had to add `LC_ALL=C` in front of the `tr` command to avoid getting `Illegal byte sequence` errors. For example: `LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!?%=' < /dev/urandom | head -c 10`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use [openSSL rand](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/rand.html) to generate the passwords:

```
PASSWORD=$(openssl rand -base64 10)
```

The above command for example will generate a string of **10** characters in **base64**.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on @Cyrus' answer here's an alternate version I've settled on after dealing with a lot of passwords in a lot of contexts:

```
# Generate a url safe password.
password() {
  local length=${1:-"10"}
  cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9~_- | head -c $length && echo
}
```

This uses only characters that don't need to be url-encoded and that are easy to select and type, and still has about 60 bits of entropy which is plenty for most purposes (I actually use a default length of 20 which has 120 bits of entropy, but I can't make an honest argument that that's necessary for security).

I also have the following:

```
# Generate a url safe password that:
# - begins with a letter, and has at least
# - one uppercase letter,
# - one lowercase letter,
# - one digit, and
# - one special character.
stupid_password() {
  while :
  do
    local pass=$(password "$1")
    [[ $pass != *[~_-]* ]] && continue
    [[ $pass != [A-Za-z]* ]] && continue
    [[ $pass != *[A-Z]* ]] && continue
    [[ $pass != *[a-z]* ]] && continue
    [[ $pass != *[0-9]* ]] && continue
    echo "$pass"
    break
  done
}
```

The filtering process is inefficient, but still essentially instantaneous. The passwords are less secure, but will work on websites that haven't read the [NIST guidelines on password complexity](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#a3-complexity)

Comment: I should say that the filtering process for `stupid_password` is essentially instantaneous for lengths greater than 5. Passwords of length 4 or 5 can take a noticeable fraction of a second to generate, and, of course, for lengths of 3 or less `stupid_password` will run forever.